# ¿Por que no suma? concatena los números

Tags: javascript, html, formulas

Este es el código, no soy programador ni nada por el estilo, lo hice siguiendo tutoriales para tener un conversor de tallas de tenis.

Al querer sumar, une los números. Ya intente con `parseInt()` pero no me ha funcionado, tal vez lo estoy colocando mal

Espero me puedan ayudar

```html
<html>
<title>Conversor de tallas</title>
<body>
<style>
body {font-family: helvetica;}
h2   {color: #FE5708;}
p    {color: black;}
</style>

<h2>Conversor de tallas</h2>
<p>Selecciona tu talla en centimetros</p>

<select name="cm" id="input" oninput="Converter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    <option value="">Centímetros</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="22">22.5</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="23.5">23.5</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="24.5">24.5</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="25.5">25.5</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="26.5">26.5</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="27.5">27.5</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="28.5">28.5</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="29.5">29.5</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="30.5">30.5</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="31.5">31.5</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="32.5">32.5</option>
</select>


<p>US M <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>

<p>US W <span id="outputMeters2"></span></p>

<p>MEX <span id="outputMeters3"></span></p>

<p>EURO <span id="outputMeters4"></span></p>

<script>
function Converter(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML=valNum-18;
  document.getElementById("outputMeters2").innerHTML=valNum-16;
  document.getElementById("outputMeters3").innerHTML=valNum-20;
  document.getElementById("outputMeters4").innerHTML=valNum+14;
  
}

</script>
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema radica es que la función no sabe qué valor tiene tu variable valNum y, por otro lado, debes pasar dicho valor de string a number.

Justo asi:

```
valNum =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value);
```

Aquí la respuesta en código:

```
function Converter(valNum) {
    valNum =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value);

    document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML= valNum-18;
    document.getElementById("outputMeters2").innerHTML=valNum-16;
    document.getElementById("outputMeters3").innerHTML=valNum-20;
    document.getElementById("outputMeters4").innerHTML=valNum+14;
    
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya hice el cambio del parseFloat y es junto lo que necesita, hay alguna forma de que solo un numero (la talla en EURO) no tenga decimales? y se redondee hacia arriba?

Answer (score 5):

La propiedad `value` del `select` es un `string`. Necesitas convertirlo con `parseInt` o `parseFloat` para preservar los decimales. Eso es todo.

Por cierto, en la parte de `onchange` te quedó un nombre diferente se la función que estás usando. Tienes que cambiarlo:

```
onchange="Converter(this.value)"
```

Así queda:

```js
function Converter(valNum) {
   valNum = parseInt(valNum)
   document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML=valNum-18;
   document.getElementById("outputMeters2").innerHTML=valNum-16;
   document.getElementById("outputMeters3").innerHTML=valNum-20;
   document.getElementById("outputMeters4").innerHTML=valNum+14;
}
```

```css
body {font-family: helvetica;}
h2   {color: #FE5708;}
p    {color: black;}
```

```html
<h2>Conversor de tallas</h2>
<p>Selecciona tu talla en centimetros</p>

<select name="cm" id="input" oninput="Converter(this.value)" onchange="Converter(this.value)">
    <option value="">Centímetros</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="22">22.5</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="23.5">23.5</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="24.5">24.5</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="25.5">25.5</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="26.5">26.5</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="27.5">27.5</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="28.5">28.5</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="29.5">29.5</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="30.5">30.5</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="31.5">31.5</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="32.5">32.5</option>
</select>


<p>US M <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>

<p>US W <span id="outputMeters2"></span></p>

<p>MEX <span id="outputMeters3"></span></p>

<p>EURO <span id="outputMeters4"></span></p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya quedo resuelto

Comment: @VlogdeSneakers Recuerda aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: Lo único que le cambiaría a la respuesta es que en lugar de usar `parseInt`, usaría `parseFloat` ya que existen tallas con decimales.

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya hice el cambio del parseFloat y es junto lo que necesita, hay alguna forma de que solo un numero (la talla en EURO) no tenga decimales? y se redondee hacia arriba?

Comment: @Vlog con [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) o `Math.ceil`.